# Can "hurl" be used as a noun in British English?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, british-english

I read the definition of the word ***hurl*** in some dictionaries: [*Collins English Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hurl) says it can be used as a noun in British English meaning "**4.** the act or an instance of hurling". However, neither [*Oxford Living Dictionaries*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hurl), nor the [*Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary and Thesaurus*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hurl) list this sense of the word.

For example, is "hurl" OK in the following?

> The hurl of the brick through the window sprang us all.

Is it alright to use ***hurl*** as a noun in British English, and if so, how commonplace is it?

Comment: What meaning are you asking about? (There are [several](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hurl) that exist.) Also, links to the dictionaries you checked would be helpful.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hurl%2Churl_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Churl%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Churl_NOUN%3B%2Cc0

Comment: For example, can I say "the hurl of the brick through the window sprang us all"?

Comment: ... No, totally unidiomatic.

Comment: @Nostradamus That sentence doesn’t even make sense. What is ‘spring’ supposed to mean? “The brick being hurled through the window made us all jump” is idiomatic, but I can’t tell if it means the same thing as what you wanted your example to mean.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: Can "spring" not be used as a transitive verb to mean "to cause to spring" as in "the hound sprang a quail" (I saw this example in the free dictionary). Yes I actually meant what you said but it seems "the hurl of the brick through the window sprang us all" is unidiomatic in comparison with "the brick being hurled made us all jump up".

Comment: @Nostradamus That seems like a very archaic use to me, but quail hunters may disagree. It definitely doesn’t work with people jumping from shock, though. You might say “he sprang up when he heard footsteps outside”, but never that the footsteps sprang him.

Comment: It is quite likely I would say, "I gave it a big hurl," if I was describing how I'd thrown something very heavy into a river. That usage might be an Australian idiom. I've also heard 'a hurl' used to mean vomiting.

Comment: I see. As for spring again, can we say it doesn't work with humans but with some non living objects, such as traps and snares. Does it also sound archaic that the rabbit sprang the trap.

Comment: Check out a [Google Ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hurl_NOUN%2C+hurl_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) on hurl as a noun vs a verb. The noun is much much less frequent than the verb.

Comment: Sure, its use as a verb is much more common. The definition of hurl at dictionary.com includes meaning 6 as a noun. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hurl

Comment: It is "all right" to use obscure words, when you can get the common ones right. Alright?

Comment: ...and "common" and "commonplace" are not synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

There is great flexibility allowed in English for speakers to use nouns, verbs, and adjectives **almost** interchangeably. You should not do so if a different word derived from the same root word already exists as the part of speech you want.

If not, then you **may** use nouns as verbs, noting the conjugation of any new verbs you invent is always regular. For example, that is how we ended up with the verb 'to google' derived from the proper noun 'Google'.

Nouns and adjectives are freely interchangeable provided there are not two different words already available for the different functions.

Verb participles (the -ing and -ed forms if the verb is regular) are always available as adjectives. Less commonly used is the bare verb. Thus, if they are adjectives they may also be used as nouns as well.

That is the theory of what is allowed, but I would urge caution if you are not a native speaker. Native speakers do these types of things all the time - but they know when what they are doing sounds natural.

If you are not a native speaker you should certainly check a dictionary carefully before attempting this; make sure there is no related word that already exists to serve the purpose you need. Even then, it would be wise to wait until you have enough experience to know something will sound natural.

Comment: Do you have anything specific to say about "hurl" used as a noun? Right now you vaguely explain [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)), but none of what you said answers the question here as the OP has already consulted dictionaries.

Comment: I have already posted two specific comments (above the answer) for 'hurl' being used as a noun. Since posting those I checked at thesaurus.com for possible alternatives. The only one that comes close is 'heave' which I expect would also be used much more frequently as a verb than a noun.

Comment: Please edit the information from your comments into your answer. Comments should be used "to ask for more information or suggest improvements".

Comment: Are you able to open an offline discussion about that?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "offline discussion". If you mean meta, ask and drop me a link. If you mean chat, you can [create a room for us](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/203046/laurel) (I don't usually chat, but I'll figure it out).

Comment: For the information of others ... I had a private chat with Laurel. She confirmed that one person with a very high reputation is "allowed" to post answers as comments. I was given a link to an explanation why that is so. That reinforced my feeling that **who you are** (your "reputation") is what matters here, not **what you do**. If anyone else feels that way I suggest they ask Laurel to post that link here. I would stress, I do see good reasons for this site's posting policies. If they were enforced equally I would be delighted and willingly comply.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it in reference to the Irish sport of hurling. The 'camàn', or rather the stick with which one plays, is usually referred to as a hurley, or more commonly, a hurl.

Not relevant to the context of your provided sentence, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s fine, but not common.

The *Oxford English Dictionary* defines **hurl** (noun) as

> 1. The action or an act of hurling; a forcible or violent cast or throw.

A similar use is the word *toss*, which is used as both a noun and verb; *toss* in either case is used more frequently than *hurl*. As shown by the definition of *hurl* the related words *throw* and *cast* can also be used as nouns; but such usage is not common in everyday English.